# How to watch contracts on Mist without ABI?

Tags: solidity, mist, abi

I've been trying to watch the Ethereum Alarm Clock contract on the main net (@ `0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b`) via Mist. This is the first time I've used Mist to watch contracts and I don't know how to get the JSON description, for example where it says:

> In order to watch and interact with a contract already deployed on the
>   blockchain you need to know its address and description of its
>   interface in JSON format.

When I enter the contract address of the Ethereum Alarm Clock I get the following error:

[image: Error in Mist]

I went to Browser Solidity and there didn't seem any way of getting the JSON description. I also checked out EtherChain and [could only get the EVM code](https://etherchain.org/account/0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b#codeDisasm) which is useless. What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

- Fill in the JSON Interface field in Mist (Ethereum Wallet) with the contract ABI (Application Binary Interface) that is listed in [Ethereum Alarm Clock 1.0.0 documentation - Scheduler ABI](http://docs.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/en/latest/abi.html#scheduler-abi) and the contract will be loaded.
- This works with versions 0.5.1 and 0.6.2, but **NOT** with 0.7.2.
- A bug report has been lodged on github.com - [Cannot load Ethereum Alarm Clock Scheduler Contract in 0.7.2 . Working in 0.6.2 . #515](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/515) . This bug has been fixed in 0.7.6 (but the [Mist freezing issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/836) when The DAO contract is in the contracts watchlist is still a problem).

---

## Further Details

### Response to additional question about checksum

The security features refers to the checksum on the address. Before the checksum feature was introduced, addresses like  `0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b` were all lowercase. I entered this address in [etherchain.org](https://etherchain.org/account/0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b) and copied the equivalent checksummed address which is `0x6C8f2A135f6ed072DE4503Bd7C4999a1a17F824B`. Both versions should work in the Ethereum Wallet.

### Here is the blank screen in Ethereum Wallet 0.7.2

A bug report has been lodged.
[image]

### Here is the working screen in Ethereum Wallet 0.6.2

A similar screen is also displayed in 0.5.1
[image]

### You may want to try 0.6.2, and check the network

You might want to try downloading the old 0.6.2 version of Ethereum Wallet and see if you can load the contract in your screen. The issue you are encountering may be a bug in the new version.

And check that you are using the Main network (menu Develop -> Network).

While submitting the bug report, I when through the recommended steps to check. One of these steps was to load the console (menu Develop -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Wallet UI). The 0.7.2 console showed the message `Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node on IPC. (...)`.

Comment: The problem still happens when I paste in the contract address, even after I put in the ABI. Is there some environmental issues with Mist?

"The address looks valid, but it doesn't have some security features that will protect you against typos, so double check you have the right one. If provided, check if the security icon matches."

Comment: I did my original testing on Ethereum Wallet 0.6.2 and it was working. I've now downloaded 0.7.2 and it is not working.

Comment: Ah, so it must be a compatibility issue. The version I'm using is 0.5.2.

Comment: I've just logged this issue on github.com - https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/515 .

Comment: One thing you may want to check is that you are on the Main Network (Menu "Develop" -> "Network"). The Ethereum Alarm Clock contract shows up correctly in Ethereum Wallet 0.5.1 as well.

Comment: I checked that. The blockchain is fully up to date on the main net.

Comment: Wait- it's actually working now. I tried the checksummed address along with the Scheduler ABI (used a different ABI before). Now it's showing up with all the relevant parameters. Thanks! (You can probably close the Github issue).

Comment: What version did you get it working with?

Comment: 0.5.2. It was my mistake- I used the ContractCall ABI instead of Scheduler. But with the right ABI and the checksummed address did the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave the Github issue open as there seems to be a problem with 0.7.2. Works with 0.5.1 and 0.6.2, and with your 0.5.2 as well. You may want to try using the non-checksummed address as this should not make a difference - just a warning to try to get people to use the safe address.