# Cannot send ETH or DAO via Ethereum Wallet (Mist)

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, gas, dao

I have DAO and ETH in my Ethereum Wallet. Every time I try to send it, I input my password and press send, and it sits there saying "confirming" for a few minutes. Eventually, it just reverts back to the password entry portion without doing anything, as though I never entered my password and pressed send. Also, it says can't estimate gas as you need 1 eth in your wallet. I have more than 1 ETH in my wallet. When I close the sending window, I get "transaction denied." Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using the latest Ethereum Wallet version [0.7.4](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.7.4). If this problem still persists after trying out the steps below, please download Ethereum Wallet version [0.6.2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.6.2) and retry the steps below.

***IPC Connection Problem***

One of the problems with the Ethereum Wallet is a dropping of the IPC connection as documented in [Github - Cannot load Ethereum Alarm Clock Scheduler Contract in 0.7.2 . Working in 0.6.2 . #515](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/515) .

When you start Ethereum Wallet, it will attempt to communicate via IPC to the `geth` Ethereum node instance. The IPC connection will work for a short time, and then fail. After about 5 minutes, the IPC connection will be re-established and you will be able to:

1. See the estimated gas
2. View the Contract READ and WRITE functions.

So, start Ethereum Wallet and wait about five minutes for the IPC connection to re-establish, then try executing your transaction.

To confirm if this is the issue you are experiencing, select the Develop -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Wallet UI menu. Then select Console in the top bar on the console to the right of window. You will see an "IPC Connection Error" message when the first failure occurs, and another message that the IPC connection is re-established after around 5 minutes.

***Freezing***

When you start the Ethereum Wallet AND you have loaded The DAO contract into the Contracts page, Ethereum Wallet will try to retrieve all the events arising from the tens of thousand transactions made to The DAO. Ethereum Wallet will operate slowly and sometimes freeze completely.

In this case, the solution is to leave Ethereum Wallet running for a few hours for the event synchronisation to complete. Then try executing your transaction.

See also [Is the Mist Wallet stable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/is-the-mist-wallet-stable/3685#3685).

Answer (score -1):

Consider accessing your coins in MIST using MEW interface and move them that way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phht73IvUDI